# Parse HTML tables to variables in Bash

Tags: html, bash

I'm trying to solve this problem: I got HTML source code and I want to extract tables and their content to variables.
For example:

```
<table>
content1
</table>
some more code
<table>
content2
</table>
```

And I would like to save first table to var1 and second table to var2 so I can write:

```
echo $var1
```

And I got:

```
<table>
content1
</table>
```

There are no identifiers how to distinguish these tables. Do you got any idea how to solve this?

Thanks

Comment: use the reg formula

Comment: I've tried my best, but I got no idea how to make regex which can separate these tables.

Comment: Sorry, lots of work... That answer is quite nice, but too specific to that example. I don't have exact number of tables. However it helped me a lot to find a way how to think about that problem, thank you.

Comment: @Majzlik: You can modify it to point to your node and extract the information accordingly. BTW it is specific, because you gave only that file to work with.

Comment: Yes, I know, sorry, it was not ment as a criticism. Thanks for that answer once again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I will break down the answer which I tried using [`xmllint`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/xmllint) which supports a `--html` flag for parsing `html` files

```
$ echo "cat //html/body/table" |  xmllint --html --shell YourHTML.html | sed '/^\/ >/d' | sed 's/<[^>]*.//g' | tr -d '\n' | awk -F"-------" '{print $1,$2}'
content1  content2
```

First you can check the sanity of your HTML file by parsing it as below which confirms if the file is as per the standards or throws out errors if seen:-

```
$ xmllint --html YourHTML.html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd">
<html><body>
<table>
content1
</table>
<table>
content2
</table>
</body></html>
```

with my original `YourHTML.html` file just being:-

```
$ cat YourHTML.html
<table>
content1
</table>
<table>
content2
</table>
```

Now for the value extraction part; The steps as they executed:-

Starting the file parsing from root-node to the repeating node (`//html/body/table`) and running `xmllint` in HTML parser & interactive shell mode (`xmllint --html --shell`)

Running the command plainly produces a result,

```
/ >  -------
<table>
content1
</table>

 -------
<table>
content2
</table>
/ >
```

Now removing the special characters using `sed` i.e. `sed '/^\/ >/d' | sed 's/<[^>]*.//g'` produces

```
content1


 -------

content2
```

Now removing the newlines from the above command using `tr` so that `awk` can process the records using the field separator as `-------`

```
content1 -------content2
```

The `awk` command on the above output will produce the file as needed; `awk -F"-------" '{print $1,$2}`

```
content1  content2
```

Putting it together in a shell script, it looks like

```
#!/bin/bash

# extract table1 value
table1Val=$(echo "cat //html/body/table" |  xmllint --html --shell YourHTML.html | sed '/^\/ >/d' | sed 's/<[^>]*.//g' | tr -d '\n' | awk -F"-------" '{print $1}')

# extract table2 value
table2Val=$(echo "cat //html/body/table" |  xmllint --html --shell YourHTML.html | sed '/^\/ >/d' | sed 's/<[^>]*.//g' | tr -d '\n' | awk -F"-------" '{print $2}')

# can be extended up-to any number of nodes
```

Or quite simply:-

```
#!/bin/bash


echo "cat //html/body/table" |  xmllint --html --shell file | sed '/^\/ >/d' | \
    sed 's/<[^>]*.//g' | tr -d '\n' | awk -F"-------" '{print $1,$2}' | \
        while IFS= read -r value1 value2
        do
            # Do whatever with the values extracted
        done
```

P.S:- The number of commands can be reduced/simplified with a reduced number of `awk`/`sed` command combination. This is just a solution that works. The `xmllint` version I have used is `xmllint: using libxml version 20706`